# Is it possible to block end users from using Javascript to trigger events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, click, dom-events

As an example, let's assume I want to prevent users from using auto-clickers. Is it possible, and are there accepted best practices when doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it is not possible. Someone can always turn off JavaScript, modify it, run their own JS-code, etc, etc. JavaScript should never ever be used for security reasons.

However, for AJAX-requests you could implement a minimum interval server-side (like on Stack Overflow).